# invisible reCAPTCHA javascript

Tags: forms, form-submit, invisible-recaptcha

I have the invisible reCAPTCHA set up, but it doesn't seem to want to call my callback function. My form looks like:

```
<form id='ContactAgentForm' name='ContactAgentForm' class='custom-form-widget-form standard_form' action='contact_agent' listing_id=1233445>
    ...
    <div class='field captcha-field recaptcha_field' >
        <div id='g-recaptcha-div' class="g-recaptcha" ></div>
    </div>

    ...

    <div class="field button-field">
        <button class="button button-primary"><span>Send</span></button>
        <a class="button button-cancel btn-close" href="#cancel"><span>Cancel</span></a>
    </div>

</form>
```

In the javascript, I want to handle the fact that there might be multiple forms on the page, so I create a list of all the forms. For each form, I attach/render the reCAPTCHA logic, attaching my callback with the form passed as a parameter:

```
<script>
    var $form_list = jQuery("form.custom-form-widget-form");

    var onFormPageSubmit = function(token, $form ) {
        console.log("Got here! ", token );
        var field = $form.find('.g-recaptcha-response')[0];
        field.value = token;
        $form[0].submit();
    };

    var onloadCallback = function() {
        $form_list.each( function() {
            var $form = jQuery(this);

            var $recaptcha = $form.find( ".g-recaptcha" );    
            if ( $recaptcha.length )
            {
                var recaptchaId = grecaptcha.render($recaptcha[0], {
                    'callback': function (token) { onFormPageSubmit(token, $form); },
                    'sitekey': "{$captcha_config.invisible_captcha_site_key}",
                    'size': 'invisible',
                    'badge': 'inline'
                });

                $form.data("recaptchaid", recaptchaId);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

And just below that, I load the recaptcha/api.js file:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit&onload=onloadCallback"></script>
```

With some judicial 'console.log' statements, we get through all of the code EXCEPT for the callback (onFormPageSubmit). The "protected by reCAPTCHA" logo is there, but it seems that the form is just submitted, ignoring the reCAPTCHA call altogether.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the line, the validation function for the form was lost (it's in another file). The validation function was attached to the button, and it executed something like this:

```
$submit_button.on( 'click', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // get the recaptchaid from form data
    var $recaptcha_id = $form.data( "recaptchaid" );
    if ( $recaptcha_id != undefined )
    {
        grecaptcha.execute($recaptcha_id);
    }
} );
```

The "grecaptcha.execute" is the important thing - this is what triggers the actual reCAPTCHA call.